# Split datafile into multiple

Tags: r

I am currently working with a Toolbox, so panel data must be contained in CSV files for each country. I have a 60 country panel for 1980-2014 quarterly data in a single CSV file. Rather than copying it manually I would like to use a looping routine. 
This is what I tried to do:

```
 mydata<-read.csv("regression.csv")
 value<-split(mydata, mydata$country, drop=FALSE)
```

As far I understand I need to use lapply to export the data into 60 CSV files. 
Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: How do you want to name the files? If you need the country name as the identifier, `lapply(names(value), function(x) write.csv(value[[x]], file=paste0(x, '.csv'), quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE))` or so

Comment: Great! This is obviously fine for me! I would want first 7 letters of country name to be a filename.

Comment: Will obviously do! Thanks for your brief response and I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop through the `names` of the `list` elements using `lapply`, get the first 7 characters of the name with `substr` and use that to create the file name in the `write.csv`

```
lapply(names(value), function(x) write.csv(value[[x]],
      file=paste0(substr(x, 1,7), '.csv'), quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE))
```